# INSERT 'X' If another column is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need to update column `firstname` in table `Taulu` ( removing single quotes ). I also need to add 'X' to another column `sq` if values where updated.
I would like to update this in one statement.

What I tried so far:

```
UPDATE Taulu set 
firstname = REPLACE(dataa, '''', ''), 
IF SELECT firstname from Taulu 
WHERE 
firstname LIKE '%''%' OR 
firstname LIKE '''%' OR 
firstname LIKE '%''' <> '' sq= 'X' 
ELSE sq= '')
```

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator, it can't be used in a `SELECT` statement. What you're after here in a `UPDATE...FROM...` Statement. [UPDATE (Transact-SQL) - L. Specifying a table alias as the target object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object)

Comment: update Taulu set firstname = REPLACE(dataa, '''', ''), sq = case when REPLACE(dataa, '''', '') = firstname then '' else 'X' end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I think:

```
UPDATE Taulu 
    SET firstname = REPLACE(dataa, '''', ''), 
        sq = 'X'
    WHERE firstname LIKE '%''%' ;
```

The `WHERE` clause should identify only the rows that will be updated (those with single quotes).  I'm not sure if the assignment to `sq` should be a simple assignment or `sq = sq + 'X'`.